# Same xml element in different places

Tags: xml, jaxb

Is such xml valid?

```
<xml>
    <foo/>
    <foo/>
    <bar/>
    <bar/>
    <foo/>
    <bar/>
</xml>
```

If it this, how should JAXB mappings look like to keep such structure?(With mapping I have created all the foos goes into single list, same with bars);

Comment: The word "valid" has no meaning without a DTD or an XML schema. The snippet is *well-formed* (i.e. there are no syntax errors), if that is what you mean.

Comment: I have schema for this document, and Intellij shows something like "Non-unique declaration name foo",this have made me suspicious.

Comment: Well in this case the document doesn't appear to be valid against that particular schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`@XmlElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html):

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="Foo", type=Foo.class),
    @XmlElement(name="Bar", type=Bar.class)
})
public List<Goo> fooOrBar;
```

This assumes `Foo` and `Bar` have a common superclass `Goo`. (In the worst case the have the common superclass `Object`.)

Another option is [`@XmlElementRefs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRefs.html), but that's a bit more complicated.